# kernel booting procedure

Tags: kernel

As we know that a OS is required a c file to execute. But when we boot a kernel then first it is decompressed but for decompressing a c function is used. til now there is no OS in the system. then how this c code is executed?

Comment: The term you are looking for is 'bootstrapping'...

Answer (score 1):

The bootloader is responsible to decompress and load the kernel and then transfer control to the uncompressed and loaded kernel. Kernel is not executed like a standard C executable. As such, there is no requirement that OS is necessary for execution of C code. As an example there are lot of embedded systems where there is no OS but the C code is executed. Also bootloader is also written in C. The only requirement for execution is that the code is loaded in the memory and control is transferred to it.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia articles about [Bootmgr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOOTMGR#Windows_Boot_Manager) and [Vmlinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vmlinux) (along with [initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd)) should give a skimming of how the process works.

Basically, when the BIOS loads the bootloader (GRUB) from the MBR of the disk, GRUB loads a small ramdisk (initrd) into the memory which is already a very lightened operating system which is able to handle the most basic process it needs to: start the real OS.

Comment: but how the C files can be executed without any OS during booting?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that you require a OS to run a C code.

Let me clarify.

when a programm is complied by GCC it genrated a Object code which act as a input to assembler which convert that Object code into Binary code which can be directly executed by the machine.

But if The GCC directly generate a Binary code their is no need of any assembler or any OS. Hence The Binary can be directly execute by the hardware instruction by instruction.